# AngularJs, $scope.variable is undefined in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my html file , I use a directive which is a searchBox:

```
<ng-lms-search-box searchType="Author" maxResult=5 data-ng-model="searchText"> </ng-lms-search-box>
```

And this is the function where I define the directive in app.js:

```
lmsModule.directive('ngLmsSearchBox', [ '$http', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace : 'true',
        $scope : {
            searchType : '@searchType',
            searchText : '@ngModel',
        },
        templateUrl : '../templates/searchBox.html',
        bindToController : true,
        link : function($scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log($scope.searchType);
            if ($scope.searchType == "Author") {
                element.bind('keyup', function() {
                    $http.post("listAuthor/" + $scope.searchText + "/1", {
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                    }).success(function(data) {
                        $scope.$emit("passData", data);
                    });
                });
            } else if ($scope.searchtype == "Publishers") {
            } else {
            }
        },
    };
} ]);
```

The `$scope.searchType` which should be "author" is, however, "undefined".

Anyone knows why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the definition, i think it's just `scope`, not `$scope`, so where you have `$scope : { searchType : '@searchType'` etc

Comment: @Jorg Hi Jorg, thanks for your prompt comment. I changed it to scope, but I still got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML should be snake-case:

```
  search-type="Author"
```

And camelCase in your directive definition.

```
 $scope.searchType
```

Comment: Thanks so much! "search-type" is the solution!

Comment: Spent more than 2 hours going round in circles because of this.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's `scope` not `$scope`:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/8cubzbgk/)

```
scope : {
    searchtype : '@searchtype',
    searchtext : '@ngModel',
},
```

And you should use all lowercase or `searchType` becomes `serch-type`

Answer (score 1):

declaring variable in the template should be with dash delimeter as below,because you have used scope variable as searchType , which is camel case. and its should be `scope` not `$scope` , inside DDO (directive defintion direcitve)

```
search-type
```

refer : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

```
<ng-lms-search-box search-type="Author" maxResult=5 data-ng-model="searchText"> </ng-lms-search-box>
```